# How to pivot_long pairs of date-var combinations with non-matching dates?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tidyr, reshape

Here is my toy data.

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
       ~date1, ~`A Equity`,       ~date2, ~`B Equity`,        ~date3, ~`C Equity`,
  "1/29/2016",          35, "10/31/2017",          67, NA_character_,    NA_real_,
  "2/29/2016",          40, "11/30/2017",          31, NA_character_,    NA_real_,
NA_character_,    NA_real_, "12/29/2017",          56, NA_character_,    NA_real_)
```

The real one has over 1000 columns and many more dates.

I want to long the data so that the desired output has only date, var, and value columns as shown below:

```
desired_df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~date,   ~var,  ~value,
   "1/29/2016",  "A",      35,
   "2/29/2016",  "A",      40,
  "10/31/2017",  "B",      67,
  "11/30/2017",  "B",      31,
  "12/29/2017",  "B",      56)
```

I tried this, but am not getting the desired result:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("date"), names_to = "dates", values_to = "date") %>% 
  pivot_longer (cols = contains("Equity"), names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>% 
  select(-dates) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(!is.na(date))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `names_to` is a character vector containing the special element `".value"`, the `values_to` value will be ignored, and the name of the value column will be derived from part of the existing column names.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rename_with(~ str_c(LETTERS[as.integer(str_extract(.x, "\\d+"))], " date"), starts_with("date")) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = c("var", ".value"),
               names_sep = " ",
               values_drop_na = TRUE)

# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   var   date       Equity
#   <chr> <chr>       <dbl>
# 1 A     1/29/2016      35
# 2 B     10/31/2017     67
# 3 A     2/29/2016      40
# 4 B     11/30/2017     31
# 5 B     12/29/2017     56
```

Comment: I am surprised there is no argument in `pivot_longer` to handle names

Comment: Instead of var1, var2,... I have stock ticker names all ending with the word "Equity". Can you suggest the changes now?

Comment: @Geet can you provide example column names? I need to know the actual pattern of column names.

Comment: Okay. I updated the dataframe df. It's just that all var* variables are stock ticker names all ending with the word "Equity".

Comment: @Geet column names with space are not valid. Please replace `A Equity` with `A_Equity` and run my code.

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks Darren, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

**Base R** solution using `reshape` (yes, it's still in there).

```
setNames(
  na.omit(
    reshape(
      as.data.frame(df), direction="long", varying=1:6, sep="")), 
  c("var","date","value","id"))

    var       date value id
1.1   1  1/29/2016    35  1
2.1   1  2/29/2016    40  2
1.2   2 10/31/2017    67  1
2.2   2 11/30/2017    31  2
3.2   2 12/29/2017    56  3
```

And if your "toy" data has more columns, just change the varying to:

```
grep("^[var|date]", names(df))
```